# javascript node.js next()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see a lot of use `next` in node.js.

What is it, where does it come from? What does it do? Can I use it client side?

Sorry it's used for example here:
http://dailyjs.com/2010/12/06/node-tutorial-5/

look for the loadUser function.

Comment: I've not seen this anywhere, and it's not referenced anywhere in the documentation. Are you sure it's not defined somewhere in the code base you're looking at?

Comment: That's far too vague. Can you give an example of context.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

This appears to be a variable naming convention in Node.js control-flow code, where a reference to the next function to execute is given to a callback for it to kick-off when it's done.

See, for example, the code samples here:

- http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/02/essential-node-js-patterns-and-snippets/

Let's look at the example you posted:

```
function loadUser(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user_id) {
    User.findById(req.session.user_id, function(user) {
      if (user) {
        req.currentUser = user;
        return next();
      } else {
        res.redirect('/sessions/new');
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/sessions/new');
  }
}

app.get('/documents.:format?', loadUser, function(req, res) {
  // ...
});
```

The `loadUser` function expects a function in its third argument, which is bound to the name `next`. This is a normal function parameter. It holds a reference to the next action to perform and is called once `loadUser` is done (unless a user could not be found).

There's nothing special about the name `next` in this example; we could have named it anything.

Comment: This is also used quite a lot in express.js but it's not `.next()`. He seems to ask about `next` as a method on an object.

Comment: Better to use `return next();`

Comment: @RyanWalton I agree

Comment: I used `return callback()` instead of `return next()`

Answer (score 45):

It is naming convention used when passing callbacks in situations that require serial execution of actions, e.g. scan directory -> read file data -> do something with data. This is in preference to deeply nesting the callbacks. The first three sections of the following article on Tim Caswell's [HowToNode](http://howtonode.org/) blog give a good overview of this:

[http://howtonode.org/control-flow](http://web.archive.org/web/20161022152112/http://howtonode.org/control-flow)

Also see the *Sequential Actions* section of the second part of that posting:

[http://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-ii](http://web.archive.org/web/20170206014827/https://howtonode.org/control-flow-part-ii)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this links. It explains a lot of things when start working with nodejs

Comment: Link is not working now. It is giving Internal Server Error

Comment: Updated links from internet archive

Comment: thank you for the links, I started using Node a few months ago but I find myself using these practices but not fully understanding them

Answer (score 11):

It's basically like a callback that **express.js** use after a certain part of the code is executed and done, you can use it to make sure that part of code is done and what you wanna do next thing, but always be mindful you only can do one `res.send` in your each **REST** block...

So you can do something like this as a simple `next()` example:

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("req:", req, "res:", res);
  res.send(["data": "whatever"]);
  next();
},(req, res) =>
  console.log("it's all done!");
);
```

It's also very useful when you'd like to have a middleware in your app...

> To load the middleware function, call app.use(), specifying the
>   middleware function. For example, the following code loads the
>   myLogger middleware function before the route to the root path (/).

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED');
  next();
}

app.use(myLogger);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.listen(3000);
```