# what is "next()" in nodejs (expressjs)?

Tags: node.js, express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript node.js next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next)

I just confused what the next() will do.  the site doesn't explain much (or I just don't get it).  Can anyone explain to me? thanks.