# nodeJs callbacks simple example

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

can any one give me a a simple example of nodeJs callbacks, I have already searched for the same on many websites but not able to understand it properly, Please give me a simple example.

```
getDbFiles(store, function(files){
    getCdnFiles(store, function(files){
    })
})
```

I want to do something like that...

Comment: an example on how to write a function that takes a callback as an argument?

Comment: yeah something like that, any simple example which help me to understand it.

Comment: A callback is a function that you pass as a parameter to another function... Google pls -> "callback javascript" -> first result

Answer (score 219, accepted):

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
  console.log('got data: '+data);
};

var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  callback('get it?');
};
```

Now open node or browser console and paste the above definitions.

Finally use it with this next line:

```
usingItNow(myCallback);
```

**With Respect to the Node-Style Error Conventions**

Costa asked what this would look like if we were to honor the node error callback conventions.

In this convention, the callback should expect to receive at least one argument, the first argument, as an error. Optionally we will have one or more additional arguments, depending on the context. In this case, the context is our above example.

Here I rewrite our example in this convention.

```
var myCallback = function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err; // Check for the error and throw if it exists.
  console.log('got data: '+data); // Otherwise proceed as usual.
};

var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  callback(null, 'get it?'); // I dont want to throw an error, so I pass null for the error argument
};
```

If we want to simulate an error case, we can define usingItNow like this

```
var usingItNow = function(callback) {
  var myError = new Error('My custom error!');
  callback(myError, 'get it?'); // I send my error as the first argument.
};
```

The final usage is exactly the same as in above:

```
usingItNow(myCallback);
```

The only difference in behavior would be contingent on which version of `usingItNow` you've defined: the one that feeds a "truthy value" (an Error object) to the callback for the first argument, or the one that feeds it null for the error argument.

Comment: So what does this look like with the error as the first parameter convention?

Answer (score 123):

A callback function is simply a function you pass into another function so that function can call it at a later time. This is commonly seen in asynchronous [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)s; the API call returns immediately because it is asynchronous, so you pass a function into it that the API can call when it's done performing its asynchronous task.

The simplest example I can think of in JavaScript is the `setTimeout()` function. It's a global function that accepts two arguments. The first argument is the callback function and the second argument is a delay in milliseconds. The function is designed to wait the appropriate amount of time, then invoke your callback function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("10 seconds later...");
}, 10000);
```

You may have seen the above code before but just didn't realize the function you were passing in was called a callback function. We could rewrite the code above to make it more obvious.

```
var callback = function () {
  console.log("10 seconds later...");
};
setTimeout(callback, 10000);
```

Callbacks are used all over the place in Node because Node is built from the ground up to be asynchronous in everything that it does. Even when talking to the file system. That's why a ton of the internal Node APIs accept callback functions as arguments rather than returning data you can assign to a variable. Instead it will invoke your callback function, passing the data you wanted as an argument. For example, you could use Node's `fs` library to read a file. The `fs` module exposes two unique API functions: `readFile` and `readFileSync`.

The `readFile` function is asynchronous while `readFileSync` is obviously not. You can see that they intend you to use the async calls whenever possible since they called them `readFile` and `readFileSync` instead of `readFile` and `readFileAsync`. Here is an example of using both functions.

Synchronous:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt');
console.log(data);
```

The code above blocks thread execution until all the contents of `test.txt` are read into memory and stored in the variable `data`. In node this is typically considered bad practice. There are times though when it's useful, such as when writing a quick little script to do something simple but tedious and you don't care much about saving every nanosecond of time that you can.

Asynchronous (with callback):

```
var callback = function (err, data) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(data);
};
fs.readFile('test.txt', callback);
```

First we create a callback function that accepts two arguments `err` and `data`. One problem with asynchronous functions is that it becomes more difficult to trap errors so a lot of callback-style APIs pass errors as the first argument to the callback function. It is best practice to check if `err` has a value before you do anything else. If so, stop execution of the callback and log the error.

Synchronous calls have an advantage when there are thrown exceptions because you can simply catch them with a `try/catch` block.

```
try {
  var data = fs.readFileSync('test.txt');
  console.log(data);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

In asynchronous functions it doesn't work that way. The API call returns immediately so there is nothing to catch with the `try/catch`. Proper asynchronous APIs that use callbacks will always catch their own errors and then pass those errors into the callback where you can handle it as you see fit.

In addition to callbacks though, there is another popular style of API that is commonly used called the promise. If you'd like to read about them then you can read the entire blog post I wrote based on this answer [here](https://www.chevtek.io/what-are-callbacks-and-promises/#promises).

Comment: [It is](http://codetunnel.io/what-are-callbacks-and-promises), and it includes a [second part](http://codetunnel.io/what-are-callbacks-and-promises#promises) about promises ;)

Comment: This is a much better explanation than accepted answer! I'd love every accepted answer here on SO to be like that - not only a piece of code that solves the problem, but also the **WHY** and the **HOW** it solves the problem. Basically, this answer and callbackhell would give you a pretty solid understanding of what callback is.

Comment: @SyedRafay glad I could help! Just noticed that link at the bottom was outdated. Here's an updated link to that blog post in case ya want it: https://www.chevtek.io/what-are-callbacks-and-promises/#promises

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of copying text file with `fs.readFile` and `fs.writeFile`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var copyFile = function(source, destination, next) {
  // we should read source file first
  fs.readFile(source, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err); // error occurred
    // now we can write data to destination file
    fs.writeFile(destination, data, next);
  });
};
```

And that's an example of using `copyFile` function:

```
copyFile('foo.txt', 'bar.txt', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    // either fs.readFile or fs.writeFile returned an error
    console.log(err.stack || err);
  } else {
    console.log('Success!');
  }
});
```

Common node.js pattern suggests that the first argument of the callback function is an error. You should use this pattern because all control flow modules rely on it:

```
next(new Error('I cannot do it!')); // error

next(null, results); // no error occurred, return result
```

Comment: what is next? What is the variable results= what's being called?

Comment: @SemicolonWarrier a pointer for me as well as others:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next

Answer (score 6):

Try this example as simple as you can read, just copy save newfile.js do node newfile to run the application.

```
function myNew(next){
    console.log("Im the one who initates callback");
    next("nope", "success");
}


myNew(function(err, res){
    console.log("I got back from callback",err, res);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

we are creating a simple function as

```
callBackFunction (data, function ( err, response ){
     console.log(response)
}) 

// callbackfunction 
function callBackFuntion (data, callback){
    //write your logic and return your result as
callback("",result) //if not error
callback(error, "") //if error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
//delay callback function
function delay (seconds, callback){
    setTimeout(() =>{
      console.log('The long delay ended');
      callback('Task Complete');
    }, seconds*1000);
}
//Execute delay function
delay(1, res => {  
    console.log(res);  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.stat('input.txt', function (err, stats) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(stats);
        console.log('Completed Reading File');
    }
});
```

'fs' is a node module which helps you to read file.
Callback function will make sure that your file named 'input.txt' is completely read before it gets executed.
fs.stat() function is to get file information like file size, date created and date modified.

Answer (score 1):

This blog-post has a good write-up:

https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

```js
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
  alert(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
  callback();
}

function alertFinished(){
  alert('Finished my homework');
}

doHomework('math', alertFinished);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Traditional JS way
function display(result) {
    console.log("Sum of given numbers is", result);
}

function calculateSum(num1, num2, callback) {
    console.log("FIrst number is", num1, "and second number is", num2);
    const result = num1 + num2;
    callback(result);
}

calculateSum(10, 20, display);
```

```
// Node JS way
const display = function(result) {
    console.log("Sum of given numbers is", result);
}

const calculateSum = function(num1, num2, callback) {
    console.log("FIrst number is", num1, "and second number is", num2);
    const result = num1 + num2;
    callback(result);
}

calculateSum(10, 20, display);
```

```
// By using anonymous function
const calculateSum = function(num1, num2, callback) {
    console.log("FIrst number is", num1, "and second number is", num2);
    const result = num1 + num2;
    callback(result);
}

calculateSum(10,20, function(result) {
    console.log("Sum of given numbers is", result)
});
```

```
// By using arrow function
const calculateSum = function(num1, num2, callback) {
    console.log("FIrst number is", num1, "and second number is", num2);
    const result = num1 + num2;
    callback(result);
}

calculateSum(10, 20, x => console.log("Sum of given numbers is", x));
```

Answer (score 0):

A `callback` is a function passed as an parameter to a `Higher Order Function` ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)). A simple implementation of a callback would be:

```
const func = callback => callback('Hello World!');
```

To call the function, simple pass another function as argument to the function defined.

```
func(string => console.log(string));
```