# Do I need to use callbacks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

```
var yModule = require('youtube-node'),
    nodeYoutube = new yModule();

nodeYoutube.setKey("key");

module.exports.getVideoLength = function (vData){
    youTube.getById(vData, function (result) {
        return convertTime(result['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']);
    })
};

var convertTime = function (time){
    var reptms = /(?:(\d+)DT)?(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?$/;
    var days = "00", hours = "00", minutes = "00", seconds = "00", formattedTime;


    //if (reptms.test(time)) {
        var matches = reptms.exec(time);
        console.log(matches);
        if (matches[1]) days = String(matches[1]);
        if (matches[2]) hours = String(matches[2]);
        if (matches[3]) minutes = String(matches[3]);
        if (matches[4]) seconds = String(matches[4]);
        formattedTime = "[" + days + ":" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "]";
        return formattedTime;
    //}
};
```

I'm struggling to understand callbacks even after reading a few things about it.
[nodeJs callbacks simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example) this helped a little, but I'm still unclear about how it works. I've spent the past hour trying to figure out how to write this using callbacks.

This module is being called by this:

```
 ytRetrieve.getVideoLength(youtube_parser(text))
```

youtube_parser's function:

```
function youtube_parser(url){
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    //console.log(match);
    if (match&&match[7]){
        return match[7].split(" ")[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `bot`? Did you create this or is it some other module?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it's the 'irc' module

Comment: This is hilarious. Username "ECMAScript" asking if callbacks are necessary :)

Short answer: yes, always, especially in node. Here's a great [resource on callbacks](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) to help you wrap your head around them. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with. Is there anything I can do to enhance this code?

Thank you for your help.

**Main.js**

```
var ytempRetrieve = require('./youtube'), ytRetrieve = new ytempRetrieve();

var ytRegex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?/;


bot.addListener('message', function (from, to, text, message) {
    if (text.match(ytRegex)) {
        console.log(text);
        youtube_parser(text, to, ytRetrieve.getVideoLength)
    }
});

function youtube_parser(url, to, callback) {
    var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
    var match = url.match(regExp);
    //console.log(match);
    if (match && match[7]) {
        callback(match[7].split(" ")[0], function (res) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                bot.say(to, match[7].split(" ")[0] + " is " + res + " long.")
            }, 1500)
        });
    }
}
```

**youtube.js**

```
var yModule = require('youtube-node'),
    nodeYoutube = new yModule(),
    apiKey = require('./config');


    var youtube = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.time = null;

    self.setAPIKey = function (key) {
        nodeYoutube.setKey(key);
    };

    apiKey.getAPIKey(self.setAPIKey);

    self.getVideoLength = function (vData, callback) {
        nodeYoutube.getById(vData, function (result) {
            callback(self.convertTime(result['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration']));
        })
    };

    self.convertTime = function (time) {
        var reptms = /(?:(\d+)DT)?(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)S)?$/;
        var days = 0, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0, formattedTime;

        //if (reptms.test(time)) {
        var matches = reptms.exec(time);
        console.log(matches);
        if (matches[1]) days = Number(matches[1]);
        if (matches[2]) hours = Number(matches[2]);
        hours += days * 24;
        if (hours.toString().length === 1) {
            hours = "0" + hours
        }
        if (matches[3]) minutes = String(matches[3]);
        if (minutes.toString().length === 1) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes
        }
        if (matches[4]) seconds = String(matches[4]);
        if (seconds.toString().length === 1) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds
        }
        formattedTime = "[" + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds - 1 + "]";
        return (formattedTime);
        //}
    };

};

module.exports = youtube;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks.  The issue with your code `youtube_parser(` is that you are *calling* the function.  A callback is a function that is passed as an argument to be called later.  If you call the function, a string is returned.  `getVideoLength` is expecting a function as an argument, not a string.

Instead use `getVideoLength(youtube_parser)`.  This actually passes in the `youtube_parser` function itself to be called later (i.e. when `getVideoLength` completes).  The arguments to `youtube_parser` may need to be `(error, url)` instead, though.

Comment: " A callback is a function that is passed as an argument to be called later." I don't understand this. And what do I do with the error parameter? I'm trying to call getVideoLength after youtube_parser returns a value.

Comment: Updated with a solution I tried that gives me a 
 undefined is not a function error

Comment: @ECMAScript what don't you understand about it?  You can pass a string, an integer, or a boolean as an argument.  Why not a function?