# Node.js class, redis response is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, redis

I have a class with two methods

```
class User {
    fetchAll(project) {
        redisClient.keys(
            'user:' + project + '*',
            function (error, response) {
                if (error) {
                    pmx.notify('user:all:fetch_failed', {error: error});
                    return false;
                }

                return response;
            }
        );
    }

    updateLastDate(project, id) {
        let time = new Date().toTimeString().slice(0, 8);
        redisClient.hset(['user:' + project + ':' + id, 'lastDate', time]);
    }
}
```

updateLastDate works fine, but fetchAll returns undefined when i try to get data like this

```
let user = new User();
let users = user.fetchAll('localhost');
console.log(users);
```

Why?

p.s. Redis lib is https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis, and node.js is 6.9.0

**Solution:**

```
fetchAll(project, callback) {
    redisClient.keys(
        'user:' + project + '*',
        function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                return callback({error: error);
            }

            return callback(null, response);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: isn't it return inside callback?

Comment: From your linked documentation: *"Note that the API is entirely asynchronous."* That means `fetchAll` **cannot** return the result. And even if `redisClient.keys` called its callback synchronously, your `return response` is inside the callback, and so returns `response` from the callback, not from `fetchAll`. But that's a side point, because `fetchAll` cannot return the information you want it to return.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example

Comment: So it must be like `fetchAll(project, callback) { ...` ?

Comment: yes, you have to use either `callback` or `Promise`