# Callback not a function NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, callback

I'm quite new in NodeJS, but I'm struggling also with concept of passing variables / objects between functions. I appreciate any help on what I am doing wrong.

Please, consider this code:

**incoming request:**

```
{ 
    sender: '32165498732165845',
    text: 'shopping',
    originalRequest: 
    { 
        sender: { id: '32165498732165845' },
        recipient: { id: '87971441647898' },
        timestamp: 1488196261509,
        message: { mid: 'mid.1488196261509:c7ccb7f608', seq: 36372, text: 'shopping' } 
    },
    type: 'facebook' 
}
```

**Extracting relevant variables:**

```
var userId = request.sender;
var listName = request.text;
```

**bot.js:**

```
var listOps = require('./listops/test.js');
listOps.setActive(function (userId, listName, callback) {
    console.log ('Here I expect a callback!');
    return callback; // This will send the message back to user.
});
```

**listops/test.js:**

```
exports.setActive = function(userId, listName, callback) {
    var message = "User number " + userId + " asks to create a list with name " + listName + ".";
    console.log(userId);
    console.log(listName);
    callback (message);
}
```

Now my issue is that in `listOps.js` the outcome of both console logs is not the value I expect, it says `[Function]` and `undefined`. Therefore I suspect, that this is a root cause for error message `[TypeError: callback is not a function]`.

I'm using Claudia.js in Lambda.

Comment: You may want to read about callbacks first http://stackoverflow.com/a/19739852/6048928 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19756960/6048928

Comment: You defined `setActive` as `function(userId, listName, callback)` yet in bot.js you are only passing an anonymous function as the first argument

Comment: So like this?
`listOps.setActive(userId, listName, callback);
                    if (callback) {
                    console.log ('Here I expect a callback!');
                    return callback;
                    };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your **bot.js** to the following:

```
var listOps = require('./listops/test.js');

listOps.setActive( userId, listName, function (message) {
      console.log ('message holds the result set in listops/test.js!');
});
```

If you want to process the message afterwards, you simply could pass it to another function:

**bot.js**:

```
var listOps = require('./listops/test.js');

var processor = function(userId, listName, message){
     ... process as desired
}

listOps.setActive( userId, listName, function (message) {
      console.log ('message holds the result set in listops/test.js!');
      process(userId, listName, message);
});
```

Comment: That looks very nice, but... where is the callback then?

Comment: The callback is the third argument of listOps.setActive.

Comment: @DavedeSade the third argument is an [anonymous function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions) expression that in-lines the callback function right there in the method call. You can learn more about function expressions and function statements [in this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because in your **listops/test.js** file you are defining a function  `exports.setActive = function(userId, listName, callback)` which accepts three arguments `userId` `listName` and `callback` while you call this function in the **bot.js** file you are passing only a function `listOps.setActive(function (userId, listName, callback) {` which is illegal as expected by the definition of the **setActive** function. You need to call this function as below

```
listOps.setActive(userId, listName, function() {
                //your stuffs here
});
```