# how can i get my local variable in loop to change global variable in node js using express framework ??

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, callback

i have object array **results** from parallel asynchronus callback, the next process i want to insert my objact array **results** to my table using looping for, but i dont now to handle my status insert.

```
var boolean = false;

  if(results.code.success === true){
    for(i=0; i<req.body.id_barang.length; i++){
      detail[i] = {
        "id_transaksi" : results.code.id_transaksi,
        "id_barang" : req.body.id_barang[i],
        "qty" : req.body.qty[i],
        "sub_total" : parseInt(req.body.sub_total[i].replace(/,.*|\D/g,''),10)
      }
      connection.query("insert into detail_transaksi set ? ", detail[i], function(err, rows){
        if(err){
          null
        } else{
          boolean = true;
        }
      })
    }
  }
  var output = {"success" : boolean}
  res.send(output);
```

Comment: You need to learn a lot about asynchronous operations in node.js and their timing.  Async callbacks happen sometime in the future.  Meanwhile, you are sending the output before any of them have completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on jfriend00's answer, `function(err, rows)` is a callback function that will execute once the query is resolved. Meanwhile, rather than waiting for the query to resolve, `var output = {"success" : boolean}` will be executed without the boolean modification in the callback.

So, in order to properly send the output, you must include your code *in the callback*, after `boolean = true;`.

Here's a great [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example) giving a basic example of callback usage in node.js.