# what is wrong with my callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

This is the file "path-info.js" that has 2 functions: pathInfo & callback. Pathinfo collects all info about file from path in the object "info", callback gets that object and returns it. Code:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");

let getInfo = function (err, someObject) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return someObject;
};

function pathInfo(path, callback) {
  let info = {};

  info.path = path; // write path info

  fs.stat(path, (err, type) => { // write type info
    if (type.isFile()) {
      info.type = "file";
    }
    if (type.isDirectory()) {
      info.type = "directory";
    } else {
      info.type = "undefined";
    }
  });

  fs.stat(path, (err, type) => { // write content info if it is file
    if (type.isFile()) {
      fs.readFile(path, "utf8", (err, content) => {
        info.content = content;
      });
    } else {
      info.content = "undefined";
    }
  });

  fs.stat(path, (err, type) => { // write childs if it is directory
    if (type.isDirectory()) {
      fs.readdir(path, (err, childs) => {
        info.childs = childs
      });
    } else {
      info.childs = "undefined";
    }
  });

  getInfo(null, info); // callback returns object "info"
}

module.exports = pathInfo;
```

I use my callback function as it was shown, for instance, here: [nodeJs callbacks simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example). Still, this code does not work and I do not why.

I call this code using file "test.js", here is the code:

```
const pathInfo = require('./path-info');
function showInfo(err, info) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error occurred');
    return;
  }

  switch (info.type) {
    case 'file':
      console.log(`${info.path} — is File, contents:`);
      console.log(info.content);
      console.log('-'.repeat(10));
      break;
    case 'directory':
      console.log(`${info.path} — is Directory, child files:`);
      info.childs.forEach(name => console.log(`  ${name}`));
      console.log('-'.repeat(10));
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Is not supported');
      break;
  }
}

pathInfo(__dirname, showInfo);
pathInfo(__filename, showInfo);
```

So the logic is that I need to give my callback the object that contains some info about directory or file. Depending on that, some console.logs will be displayed.

**Any help will be appreciated!**

**UPD**: updated the code, just renamed my "callback" function to "getInfo".

Comment: Define "does not work'.

Comment: This is because you declared a variable called `callback` in your `path-info.js`. Rename it and it will solve your problem.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: @DaveNewton At this moment it writes "Is not supported", but I am 100% sure that there should be another console.log (not default case..)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ renamed it to "getInfo" (just another name), still does not work..

Comment: could you log the complete info-object in your callback

Comment: @EvgenyKobzev Can you update the code of the question with the modification ? It will avoid other to answer like me ;o)

Comment: @Satpal sure and I use its asynchronous structure, in callback I assign info.type the value in relation to what type is it. I think there is no mistake in that piece of code.

Comment: @EvgenyKobzev @SatPal means that "when you call the callback all your `fs.stat` calls are not ended, so the object you pass to `callback` is empty => `{}`".

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I updated the file.. plus I logged info-object in the callback and it send me that: 
`{ path: '/Users/kobz/WebstormProjects/netology' }
{ path: '/Users/kobz/WebstormProjects/netology/test.js' }`

There is only "path" property, while others are missing..

Comment: @EvgenyKobzev This what we are saying about the `asynchrony` of your calls: not all calls are ficniehd when you call `callback` so your object is empty or not complete.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ sadly, but I am not allowed to use promises in this task :(( So I should try to solve that task whit what I´ve got..(

Comment: @EvgenyKobzev And what about the posted answer from Kamesh ?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ I need to solve that task without external modules :( Surely this is the right one, but I´ve got restrictions..

Comment: @Bee157 now it logs `{ path: '/Users/kobz/WebstormProjects/netology' } { path: '/Users/kobz/WebstormProjects/netology/test.js' }` and as @ADreNaLiNe-DJ noticed my callbacks are not finished when i call getInfo callback to return info object.

Comment: In your function pathInfo, replace getInfo(null, info);  with callback(null, info); Your callback is function send to your internal function, so execute it. you call it callback, execute callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested.. I found a solution and it works! As @ADreNaLiNe-DJ correctly stated, my callbacks are not finished when i call getInfo callback to return info object. So the way out is to change my level of abstraction: all i´ve done is pasted my callbacks inside functions. See that code:

```
"use strict";
const fs = require("fs");

let pathInfo = (path, callback) => {
  let info = {};
  info.path = path;

  fs.stat(path, (err, type) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (type.isFile()) {
      info.type = "file";
      fs.readFile(path, "utf8", (err, content) => {
        info.content = content;
        info.childs = undefined;
        callback(err, info);
      });
    }
    if (type.isDirectory()) {
      info.type = "directory";
      fs.readdir(path, (err, childs) => {
        info.childs = childs;
        info.content = undefined;
        callback(err, info);
      });
    }
  });
};

let showInfo = (err, info) => {     // Отсюда и ниже вставлен код из текста
  if (err) {                        // из домашнего задания
    console.log('Возникла ошибка при получении информации');
    return;
  }

  switch (info.type) {
    case 'file':
      console.log(`${info.path} — является файлом, содержимое:`);
      console.log(info.content);
      console.log('-'.repeat(10));
      break;
    case 'directory':
      console.log(`${info.path} — является папкой, список файлов и папок в ней:`);
      info.childs.forEach(name => console.log(`  ${name}`));
      console.log('-'.repeat(10));
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Данный тип узла не поддерживается');
      break;
  }
};

pathInfo(__dirname, showInfo);
pathInfo(__filename, showInfo);
```

PS: sorry for Russian console.logs, hope it won't disturb you (they don't bring any value anyway into understanding how it works)

Answer (score 0):

A **callback** is a function you pass as parameter to another function.

In your case, your second parameter is function **showInfo** which is your callback. Your function *pathInfo* accepts two parameters, second is **showInfo**.

So when you call it, you execute code within **showInfo** with some parameters, usually err, then something else.

In your case, you name second parameter "**callback**" in **showInfo**, so you have to execute it with asked parameters (err and info).

Example:

```
function myfunc (parameter,cb) {
    cb(null,{});
}

myfunc("one", function (err,res) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

where "**cb**" in "**myfunc**" is function sent as second parameter.

It can be write like this as you did it:

```
var cb = function (err,res) {
    console.log(err);
}

myfunc("one",cb);
```