# Error callback is not a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm quite new to JS and I don't really understand callbacks and I have looked for a fix for this error but I can't seem to find it.
When I execute the code I get this error : TypeError: callback is not a function -> callback(false);

```
function doesLobbyExist(a, callback) {
  lobbyExists(a, function(random_data) {
    callback(random_data);
  });
}
function lobbyExists(a, callback) {
  if(lobbies.length > 0){
        lobbies.forEach(function(l) {
            if(l.lobbyName == a){
                console.log(a+" exists!");
                callback(true);
            }
        });
    }else{
        callback(false);
    }
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
doesLobbyExist(a.ln, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
```

P.S. the code goes through `console.log(a+" exists!");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce what you're seeing. Running your code under a couple of different conditions, I got the following results:

```
> var lobbies = [{ lobbyName: 'foo' }];
> doesLobbyExist('foo', console.log)
foo exists!
true
> doesLobbyExist('bar', console.log)
...
> var lobbies = [{ lobbyName: 'foo' }, { lobbyName: 'bar' }, { lobbyName: 'foo' }];
> doesLobbyExist('bar', console.log)
bar exists!
true
> doesLobbyExist('foo', console.log)
foo exists!
true
foo exists!
true
...
> var lobbies = [];
> doesLobbyExist('foo', console.log)
false
```

but there a couple of problems in your code:

- `lobbyExists` only gives a `false` response if there are no lobbies to check, it's possible for it to call the callback multiple times if there are multiple lobbies with the same name, and it doesn't return anything if a lobby isn't found.
- there's no *easy* way to break out of `forEach`. since you only want to call your callback function once, you'll want to either `return` or `break` once a lobby has been found. switching over to a `for i` loop allows us to do either one.
- comparison using == is what's known as loose or abstract equality, which may cause errors down the road - you can read up on the difference between loose (==) and strict (===) equality [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).
- if the `lobbyExists` function is only iterating through an array, then there's no need to treat it as asynchronous and use a callback. synchronous callbacks are a thing, and are perfectly fine to use, but it's something to be aware of as you continue to develop.

with all that being said, these are the changes that I would suggest:

```
function doesLobbyExist(a, callback) {
    lobbyExists(a, function(random_data) {
        //possibly do other things to random_data...

        callback(random_data);
    });
}

function lobbyExists(a, callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < lobbies.length; i++) {
        var l = lobbies[i];

        if(l.lobbyName === a) {
            console.log(a + " exists!");

            callback(true);

            return;
        }
    }

    callback(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're overcomplicating things, callbacks are simple to understand when you get the basic concept. I'll just try to leave a little primer on callback functions here and perhaps you can figure out where you went wrong in your own implementation. Consider the following code:

```js
function lobbyExists(a, callback) {
  if (a === 1) {
    callback(true);
  } else {
    callback(false);
  }
}

lobbyExists(1, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});

lobbyExists(0, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

In this case, you are passing the entire `function(response) { console.log(response); }` function as a reference in the variable `callback` in `lobbyExists`. This means when executing `lobbyExists`, the variable `callback` now refers to that function. When you say `callback(true)` you are therefore calling `function(response) { console.log(response); }` where `response` is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I executed the code snippets and it worked fine for me.
Run the code below.

```js
var lobbies = [{lobbyName:"a"}]

function doesLobbyExist(a, callback) {
  lobbyExists(a, function(random_data) {
    callback(random_data);
  });
}

function lobbyExists(a, callback) {
    if(lobbies.length > 0){
        var bool = false
        lobbies.forEach(function(l) {
            if(l.lobbyName == a){
                bool = true;
            }
        });
        callback(bool);
        return false;
    }
    callback(false);
}

doesLobbyExist("a", function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

However I changed lobbyExists function a little since callback would not call if there was no match found.

If you couldn't make it work try changing the variable name of callbacks in each function 
Ex : Instead of "callback" use "cb"

[More about callbacks](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/callbacks-in-node-js-how-why-when-ac293f0403ca)

[Similar question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example)