# What is call back function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

As per my knowledge, A callback is a function which is called when a task is completed, thus helps in preventing any kind of blocking and a callback function allows other code to run in the meantime. Callback is called when task get completed and is asynchronous equivalent for a function.

But, i am not able to implement in real time, can anyone here can help me to how to write a call back function for simple **app.js** application? and i need to know how to call a function.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodeJs callbacks simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739755/nodejs-callbacks-simple-example)

Comment: Can you please write a call back function for Mysql and Node.js connection and explain each term in simple way?