# Node.js mysql import query result outside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I am making a website where i need to import data from database and use it later in program. But when i am using npm package `mysql` i can't find any way to import result of query outside function for later use. Here is an example of my code.

Function with that i get data from database:

```js
    let output;
        dba.query('SELECT * FROM `movies-web`.movies;',(err, rows) => {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                output = rows;
            }
        });
```

And in code i use it like this:

```js
res.write(output);
```

But the variable `output` return `undefined`.


I am solving this problem for longer than month, i browsed so many pages, questions here on stackoverflow and i can't find working solution.

Comment: you're responding with the output before the query has been executed. You should move `res.write` inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

You can't write code like that, I suggest you read about callback documents and learn how to use asynchronous in the node is

- https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/
- https://www.w3resource.com/node.js/nodejs-programming-model.php
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739852/6759368

Your code should write like that:

```js
dba.query('SELECT * FROM `movies-web`.movies;',(err, rows) => {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            } else {
                res.write(rows)
            }
        });
```

**P.S:**

A better scenario for use callback:

```js
const http = require('http');

function executeQuery(next) {
  dba.query('SELECT * FROM `movies-web`.movies;',(err, rows) => {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      next(err);
      return
    }
    
    next(null, rows);
  });
}

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  executeQuery(function (error, output) {
    if (error) {
      res.writeHead(400);
      res.end(error.message);
      return;
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(JSON.stringify(output));
  });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: You should never `throw` in an asynchronous callback, no.

Comment: Yes, you to be right, I fix this sample for a better experience