# MEAN Stack - what's the purpose of returning next() inside a router.param exec function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, meanjs

I'm learning MEAN stack with an awesome tutorial online. In it, there is a [section about preloading objects](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#pre-loading-objects) by id using express's param().

```
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});
```

My question are:

1. Where can I find the API documentation on the exec() function? Is it a Mongoose function? How can I tell if it's a Mongoose function or JS or express function?
2. What's the purpose of final `return next()` here? Is it necessary in the exec() function to have `return next()`? What would happen if that line is absent? I have read that next() is for the next middleware, but in other functions from the tutorial, like below, there is no final `next()` or `return next()`. What's the difference between `next()` and `return next()` anyways?

   ```
   router.post('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
     var post = new Post(req.body);

     post.save(function(err, post){
       if(err){ return next(err); }

       res.json(post);
     });
   });
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please read document of every library you used, if you read just document of mongoose you figure out what is the `exec()` !

Ok now we can focus on the point

Q1: The `exec()` is mongoose function. if you being stuck in this situation which you can't figure out what's going on in code, please [check this out](http://devdocs.io).
this web app can help you when you need some info about functions (methods) , properties or ... (work perfectly in offline times).

Q2: [Please read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next) (By the way i think your last question is duplicated)

Answer (score 0):

MEAN is using express.
next() tells the express server to go to invoke the next middleware.
http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

The exec is not expressjs by the way.

Comment: as for return next() and not just next(), its is coding convention to call return after calling a callback (in this case next).