# NodeJs what happen when Token is correct on next() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm newbie in using Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens, i read [this document](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) on scotch.io but i cant understand when Token is correct what happen after next() method

```
apiRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {          
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });      
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;  
                next();
            }
        });

    } else {
        ...
    }

});

apiRoutes.get('/', function(req, res) {
    ...
});

apiRoutes.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    ...
});

apiRoutes.get('/check', function(req, res) {
    ...
});

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.listen(port);
```

User must be pass other request after that (my mean is after token is correct)?

i think in this sample code / route will be call after check token and it was correct,ok? how can i choose other method to call, because / is calling after next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually next() asking for nodejs to go on for next step it's whatever in node.js async loop. Javascript actually single threaded so next will call whatever method placed at stack. if you will not call next() your program will stuck. and will not call any other method after this token middleware which you have passed to `.use`

In this particular scenario it will call the next route after verified by this token middleware, which you are passing as a anonymous function.

also have a look at this method
[javascript node.js next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next)

Comment: i think in this sample code `/` route will be call after check token and it was correct,ok? how can i choose other method to call, because `/` is calling after `next()`

Comment: It's not necessary that it will call / route. Every method executed by user and is using apiRouter will go through this middleware. it can be / /users /whatever and so on.

Comment: then this is only middleware and for each request called automatically is it right? passed method after that may be were  something

Comment: off-course. also you can pass any number of middlewares.