# How to end loop in Express.js to see some under "*"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I trying to use a loop within Express.js and cannot end it.

My loop always writes "hello" I print after `/hello/SomeNumber` (for example `/hello/5`) and show me 5 hello's.

I want it to stop after `>3` and display the message under "*".

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:numbers", function(req, res) {
  var word = req.params.word;
  var numbers = Number(req.params.numbers);
  var lol = ""
  for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
    lol += word + " ";
  }
  res.send(lol);
});


app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log("Server has started!!!");
});
```

Comment: Use the [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:numbers", function(req, res) {
    var word = req.params.word;
    var numbers = Number(req.params.numbers);
    if (numbers > 3) {
        res.send("Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?");
    } else {
        var lol = ""
        for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
            lol += word + " ";
        }
        res.send(lol);
    }

});
```

**Edit: My answer was no longer accepted after OP accepted Enthusiastic Developer's answer, which as far as I know will give error cause, `next()` is inside a loop, which will give error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`**

If you definitely want to use a middleware to catch all the requests then here:

```
app.get("/repeat/:word/:numbers", function(req, res, next) {
    var word = req.params.word;
    var numbers = Number(req.params.numbers);
    if (numbers > 3) {
        next();
    } else {
        var lol = ""
        for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
            lol += word + " ";
        }
        res.send(lol);
    }
});


app.all("*", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?");
});
```

Comment: Thanks it was nice solution and work fine, but i have a question about what next() doing? this  work only in node\express? or everywhere in js?

Comment: Here you can read about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384526/javascript-node-js-next

Answer (score 0):

use break;

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
  if(i>3)
  break;
   lol +=  word + " ";
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's just cheating for Karma lol. You shouldn't take the simple suggestion from the comments and post an answer, bad form.

Comment: I didnt see your comment , when i posted it.

Comment: Lol, it's ok man I'm mostly joking around and only a little serious. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Man, the guys above dont unterstand the task. You need to jump to the next middleware if the count of iterations more than 3, right ?

Try this:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/repeat/:word/:numbers', function(req, res, next) {
  var word = req.params.word;
  var numbers = Number(req.params.numbers);
  var lol = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
    if (i > 3) next()
    lol += word + ' ';
  }
  res.send(lol);
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log('Server has started!!!');
});
```

Comment: yes you understand my task! But micro missclick i'd mean !=3  =)

Comment: @ArtemMazur Is this working fine for you? I saw you chose this as your answer after choosing mine. I am doing the same without any need of extra middleware. Also, this answer will send response multiple times as `next()` is inside a loop, which will give you error `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: @SookieSingh yes i have this error , but next() i think should work like i want , if i write >3 work fine ,but if write like i need !=3 i have this error

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve it. Add an if statement in your loop that checks if the number > 3. If it is, use `break` to stop the loop and assign the text from the * route to the `lol` variable. Then at the end of your route function when 'res.send' is called, it either contains n * hallo or **"Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?"**

Here's the code. I hope this helps.

```js
app.get("/repeat/:word/:numbers", function(req, res) {
  var word = req.params.word;
  var numbers = Number(req.params.numbers);
  var lol = ""
  for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
    if (numbers > 3) {
      break;
      lol = 'Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?';
    } else {
      lol += word + " ";
    }
  }
  res.send(lol);
});


app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Sorry, page not found...What are you doing with your life?");
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log("Server has started!!!");
});
```